# DYNAMOOSE-Set unique constraint in model level

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

How to set the unique property to DynamoDB using dynamoose node module which it 'll helps in eliminating duplicate entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table whose schema uses the attribute you want to keep unique as the primary key. Or, to separate business logic from your schema design you can use a content-based key that hashes the unique property using SHA256, and use the hash value as the partition of your table.